# Powershell Redirect URI

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to invoke a web application url using "Invoke-WebRequest" in Powershell and when I invoke the "internal.com" url, it gets redirected to another webpage whose url is ".../xyz.aspx" which accepts only the email as an input and get authenticated.

I am using the following code (as suggested by Thomas) and tried different permutations and combinations.

```
$firstRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://XYZ.internal.com/' -SessionVariable mySession
$firstRequest.Forms[0].Fields["$txtEMAIL"] = "xyz@xyz.com"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $firstRequest.BaseResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri -Body $firstRequest -WebSession $mySession
```

I am getting following message when I am running the above code.

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.
At line:9 char:18
+ ... ndRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($baseUri + $firstRequest.Forms[0] ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ProtocolViolationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.ProtocolViolationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your error message does not fit to the code provided. Please be accurate on what you are doing or nobody will be able to replicate what you get.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in your code, your second request is completely unrelated to your first request. You have to use one session instead. And you should not rely on the "next" URI you think will come, but use the URI the form will call:

```bsh
# Do your first request to obtain the login form and start maintaining one session
$baseUri = 'https://XYZ.internal.com'
$firstRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $baseUri -SessionVariable mySession

# Fill out your login form
$firstRequest.Forms[0].Fields["$txtEMAIL"] = "xyz@xyz.com"

# Use the URI defined in the action of your form to send your request to while maintaining your session
$secondRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($baseUri + $firstRequest.Forms[0].Action) -Body $firstRequest -WebSession $mySession
```

Note that you define your `SessionVariable` without a `$`, but use it later with a `$`.

If your second request does not already return your desired website, repeat the steps for the second request accordingly (using the form/body of `$secondRequest` to create `$thirdRequest` and so on).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried your answer as part of different permutations and combinations but I end up in getting the same page again. I tried with the following, please correct me if I am wrong.
$aURI = $firstRequest.BaseResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri

1. As "$firstRequest.Forms[0].Action" returned only part of the absoluteuri, tried with $aURI
2. After this, I got "Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type" error

so I tried with the below but got error page
$body = @{txtEMAIL = "XYZ@xyz.com"}
$secondRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $aURI -Body $body

Comment: @SuC I modified my answer to cover a relative path in your form action. If you have problems with this solution, please post a new question OR if still suitable, edit this question. It is very hard to read your code and error messages from the comments; always put that into a post with code formatting and readable line endings.

Comment: Edited the Post as you suggested with the error message that I am getting. Could you please check and let me know what needs to be corrected.

Comment: @SuC Looks like your initial login page is more complex than just a login. Then you have to be more specific on what you submit. Try replacing `-Body $firstRequest` by `-Body $firstRequest.Forms[0]`.

Comment: @SuC In general: I cannot TSHOOT every next to expect error message for you. If you want to automate your web login, understand your website first! Have a look at its source code. Examine the form, how does it work, what inputs does it have, what is the action. Then have a look at [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7) and replicate what you have learned from your source.

Comment: @SuC You also might check out [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.